# somehow SharePoint:CssLink cause crash of pull down refresh in mobile

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am in a sp project, and our web application not refreshing with pulling down screen in mobile, I checked master page and I found if I remove this line refresh works fine

but of course, css files not loaded properly.

How can I make it work with minimum changes in my project?

Here is my master page definition;

```
    <!-- ===== STARTER: Favicon / Windows Tile ======================================================================================== --> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Maliye/img/favicon.ico %>" runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:SPPinnedSiteTile runat="server" TileUrl="~/Style Library/Mile/img/milelogo.png" TileColor="#0072C6" />              

    <!-- ===== STARTER: Page Title loaded from page or page layout ==================================================================== -->
    <SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </SharePoint:PageTitle>

    <!-- ===== STARTER: SP Scripts and CSS  =========================================================================================== -->
    <SharePoint:StartScript runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15" />
    <SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:PageRenderMode runat="server" RenderModeType="Standard" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server" />

    <!-- ===== STARTER: Additional header placeholder - overridden by asp:content on pages or page layouts  =========================== -->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true" />

    <!-- ===== STARTER: Core SharePoint CSS =========================================================================================== -->
    <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly">
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
    </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>      
    <!-- ===== STARTER: Custom CSS  =================================================================================================== -->
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Maliye/css/bootstrap.min.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Maliye/css/swiper.min.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Maliye/css/style.min.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Maliye/css/media.min.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- ===== STARTER: SP IDs / Prefetch SP images / SP Form  =========================================================================== -->
    <SharePoint:SPClientIDGenerator runat="server" ServerControlID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain;DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea;DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" />
    <SharePoint:ImageLink runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:SharePointForm onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}" runat="server">
    ...
```